# Split string at upper/lower case boundaries

Tags: python, regex, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to split the following string at the upper/lower-case boundaries. How might I do this in Python and/or with a regex?

For example,

```
x = 'aagaaggagatataccATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAAgaaaacctgtacaa'

split_boundaries(x) = ['aagaaggagatatacc', 
                       'ATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAA',
                       'gaaaacctgtacaa']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```
import re
x = 'aagaaggagatataccATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAAgaaaacctgtacaa'

re.findall(r'[a-z]+|[A-Z]+', x)
# ['aagaaggagatatacc', 'ATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAA', 'gaaaacctgtacaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to split string to a list based on case.

```
x = 'ATGAaagaaggagatatacAcATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAAgaaaacctgtacaaAaa'

l=[]
lstr=''
ustr=''


def createList(s):
    l.append(s)

for i in list(x):
    if i.islower():
        lstr+=i
        if ustr != '':
            createList(ustr)
        ustr = ''
    elif i.isupper():
        if lstr != '':
            createList(lstr)
        ustr+=i
        lstr=''

if list(x)[-1].islower():
    createList(lstr)
else:
    createList(ustr)

print(l)
```

Output

```
['ATGA', 'aagaaggagatatac', 'A', 'c', 'ATGAATTTGTCGGTTTACCCCAATTTAACCAAA', 'gaaaacctgtacaa', 'A', 'aa']
```